# JScrollPane с JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

интересует следующий момент. Считываю help из файла, записываю его в JTextArea, после добавляю в JScrollPane. Так как это нечто на подобии мануала, то мне необходимо, чтобы текст в JTextArea не менялся, поэтому я сделал `helpText.setEnabled(false);` из-за этого программа перестала выдавать необходимый результат (текст пропал).

Результат при `helpText.setEnabled(false);`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат без этой строки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    File helpFile = new File("help.help");
    JTextArea helpText = new JTextArea();
    helpText.setEnabled(false);
    helpText.setDisabledTextColor(Color.decode("#FFFFFF"));
    JcrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(helpText);
    pane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);                
    pane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
    JDialog help = new JDialog(mainActivity, "Help");
    help.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int widthActivity = (dimension.width - 800) / 2;
    int heightActivity = (dimension.height - 600) / 2;
    help.setBounds(widthActivity, heightActivity, 800, 600);
    help.getContentPane().add(pane);
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(helpFile.toString()), "cp1251"))) {
        String s;
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while((s=br.readLine())!=null){
            sb.append(s).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }
        String text = sb.toString();
        helpText.setText(text);
        }
    catch (IOException e1) {
        logger.error("Ошибка при чтении файла помощи");
    }                        
    helpText.setDisabledTextColor(Color.decode("#FFFFFF"));
    help.setVisible(true);
```

Если убрать строку `helpText.setEbale(false);` то программа будет выдавать необходимый результат. Но у меня цель такова, чтобы текст нельзя было редакторовать.

Можно еще каким-нибудь способом ограничить ввод в JTextArea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен метод [`TextComponent#setEditable(boolean);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TextComponent.html#setEditable(boolean))

---

```
JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setText("hello\nhello");
textArea.setEditable(false);
jFrame.add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
jFrame.setSize(200,200);
jFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
jFrame.setVisible(true);
jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```